# C# 9 default implementations causing errors

Tags: c#-9.0, default-interface-member

I have been having issues with default implementations in c# 9.
Here is my problem. Each time I try to use the default implementation, I get this error
'ToyotaCorolla' does not contain a definition for 'canOffroad' and no accessible extension method 'canOffroad' accepting a first argument of type 'ToyotaCorolla' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [carApp]

Here is the interface:

```
public interface ICar
{
   
    string Model{get;}
    PaintColor Paint{get; set;}
    string[] Passengers {get;}
    void addPassenger(string passenger);
    int MaxSpeed{get;}

    void drive();
    void openDoor();
    bool canOffroad => false;

}
```

Here is part of the class(no canOffroad)

```
public class ToyotaCorolla : ICar
{
    public string Model => "Toyota Corolla";
    public PaintColor Paint{get; set;}
    public string[] passengers = new string[6];
    public virtual int MaxSpeed => 190;

    public string[] Passengers => passengers;

    


    public void addPassenger(string passenger)
    {
        bool added = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < passengers.Length; i ++)
        {
            if (passengers[i] == null)
            {
                passengers[i] = passenger;
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (added == false)
        {
            WriteLine("The passenger could not be added(too many passengers in car)");
        }
    }



    public void drive()
    {
        WriteLine("The car is driving");
    }

    public void openDoor()
    {
        WriteLine("The car door is opening");
    }
}
```

And here is the part of the main method causing the issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var JeepWrangler = new JeepWrangler();
   var corola1 = new ToyotaCorolla();
   WriteLine(corolla1.canOffroad);//causes compiler error

   WriteLine(JeepWrangler.canOffroad);//works fine(overrides default interface method in class)
}
```

I have looked at many websites and it appears to look the exact same as their examples. Additionally I know I imported the namespace into the main method correctly as both corolla1 and JeepWrangler classes are in the same file as the ICar interface.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Side note: please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - right now there is no way to know what `corolla1` is nor how `JeepWrangler` constant/class look like. If duplicate does not answer your question makes sure to [edit] the question to provide above details as well as explanation why duplicate was not enough.

Comment: DIMs work. You have to cast to the interface to use its implementation though. That's no different than explicit interface implementations. If you used `ICar corola1 = new ToyotaCorolla();` there would be no compile error

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much. I made the change but this causes an issue in another part of my code not shown in code above `foreach(var element in corola1.passengers)`. I think this is due to the fact that the passengers field is not part of the interface and fields cannot be added to interfaces. Is their anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: @DanielKohn why do you use a public field when you already have a public property? That's the real bug. Fields are implementation details, private or not. Having a get-only property in an interface doesn't prevent implementers from having a property with a setter